# Issue with Merging in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am having issues in merging 2 pandas dataframes.

```
a = [{'City':'CCC','ID':'BBB'},{'City':'AAA','ID':'DDD'},{'City':'CCC','ID':'HHH'}]
b = [{'City':'AAA','Name':'FFF'},{'City':'CCC','Name':'GGG'}]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on='City')
```

df1:

```
   City ID
0   CCC BBB
1   AAA DDD
2   CCC HHH
```

df2:

```
    City Name
0   AAA  FFF
1   CCC  GGG
```

df3:

```
    City ID     Name
0   CCC  BBB    GGG
1   AAA  DDD    FFF
2   CCC  HHH    GGG
```

In the above mock code, `df3['Name']` has no `NaN` values. But, in my real dataframes (which I can't share here), the equivalent of `df3['Name']` has `NaN` values although it shouldn't because all elements in `df1['City']` and `df2['City']` match in my real dataframes (not these mock dataframes). So, I try to troubleshoot and find the followings.

If I try the following code,

```
'AAA' in df1['City']
```

I get `False` although it should be `True` since `'AAA'` is in that column.

But, if I try the following code,

```
'AAA' in sorted(df1['City'])
```

I get `True`, which is what I expect.

Also, to confirm, I try this:

```
len([x for x in df1['City'] if x not in df2['City']])
```

And got output of `3`, which should be `0`.

So, I wonder what's the causes of the above issues and any guess on why the merging of the real dataframe is not working? The elements of the column used for merging are string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't get any `NaN` in this example because every element of the `'City'` column in `df1` was in the `'City'` column of `df2`.

Try this example instead

```
a = [
    {'City':'CCC','ID':'BBB'},
    {'City':'AAA','ID':'DDD'},
    {'City':'CCC','ID':'HHH'},
    {'City':'DDD','ID':'XXX'}
]

b = [
    {'City':'AAA','Name':'FFF'},
    {'City':'CCC','Name':'GGG'}
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='left',on='City')
df3

  City   ID Name
0  CCC  BBB  GGG
1  AAA  DDD  FFF
2  CCC  HHH  GGG
3  DDD  XXX  NaN
```

---

You can check if `'AAA'` is in `df3.City`

```
(df3.City == 'AAA').any()

True
```

Or

```
'AAA' in df3.City.tolist()

True
```

Comment: Thank you and @jezrael for your detailed answers. I appreciate it. I learned many things. 2 conclusions: 1) my bad with using `in`, 2) I had a typo with my question. The NaN was observed in `df3['Name']` and I have just found out that `df2['Name']` has some NaN entries. So, it was not about the matching issues. Thank you very much! Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First you badly check `AAA` - need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check multiple values or compare with `Series` and if need scalar output add [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) for check at least one `True`.

See also [using the in operator](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator).

```
#this check in index, not in values
print ('AAA' in df1['City'])
False

print (0 in df1['City'])
True
```

---

```
#this check in list from column
print (sorted(df1['City']))
['AAA', 'CCC', 'CCC', 'DDD']

print ('AAA' in sorted(df1['City']))
True

#pandas function for checking multiple values is isin
print (df1['City'].isin(['AAA', 'EEE']))
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: City, dtype: bool

print (df1['City'].isin(['AAA', 'EEE']).any())
True
```

---

```
print (df3['City'] == 'AAA')
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: City, dtype: bool

print ((df3['City'] == 'AAA').any())
True
```

And you get `NaN`s in column `City` in output, because no match - it show another answer.

You can get difference values by :

```
#borrowed sample from piRSquared's answer
a = [
    {'City':'CCC','ID':'BBB'},
    {'City':'AAA','ID':'DDD'},
    {'City':'CCC','ID':'HHH'},
    {'City':'DDD','ID':'XXX'}
]

b = [
    {'City':'AAA','Name':'FFF'},
    {'City':'CCC','Name':'GGG'}
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b)


print (np.setdiff1d(df1['City'], df2['City']))
['DDD']
```

Or `isin` for check multiple values, `~` is for invert boolean mask.

Then is possible use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
print (~df1['City'].isin(df2['City']))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: City, dtype: bool

print (df1[~df1['City'].isin(df2['City'])])
  City   ID
3  DDD  XXX

print (df1.loc[~df1['City'].isin(df2['City']), 'City'])
3    DDD
Name: City, dtype: object
```